# Navigating with "Enter" focuses Button on other page

Tags: c#, uwp

I have one "login page" and one "content page". The login page consists of a `PasswordBox` and a `Button`. When the button is clicked or the Enter-key is pressed in the `PasswordBox`, I want the program to navigate to the next page. Navigating with the button works fine, but when the page is changed due to the pressed enter key, the `Button` on the next page is focused. How can I disable/avoid this behaviour?

"Focused" button: [image]

---

MainPage.xaml

```
<Page
    x:Class="TabNavigation.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TabNavigation"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <PasswordBox x:Name="textBox" KeyDown="HandleTextBox_KeyDown"/>
            <Button x:Name="loginButton" Content="Einloggen" Click="HandleLoginButton_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;

namespace TabNavigation {
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page {
        public MainPage() {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void HandleTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e) {
            if(e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Enter) {
                this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(ContentPage));
            }
        }

        private void HandleLoginButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(ContentPage));
        }
    }
}
```

ContentPage.xaml

```
<Page
    x:Class="TabNavigation.ContentPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TabNavigation"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <Button>Test</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can cancel the focus in `GettingFocus`:

```xml
 <Button GettingFocus="Button_GettingFocus">Test</Button>
```

```cs
private void Button_GettingFocus(UIElement sender, GettingFocusEventArgs args)
 {
   args.Cancel = true;
 }
```

Old answer:

You have few options:

- Disable focus on button with `IsTabStop=false`
- Change `TabIndex` to larger integer than other elements.
- Set focus from your code to something else: `otherControl.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);`

Comment: The problem with these options is that they only postpone my issue, but don't solve it. The effect of the first two possibilities simply is that some other control is focused. I have tried to focus a `TextBlock` with your third method, but this doesn't work. I could only focus another button or something like this, but this doesn't bring any benefit to me.

Comment: So you want to disable focus for all elements? Or what are you trying to achieve in the end?

Comment: When I navigate to the next page by clicking `loginButton`, the button on the next page is not focused. But when I navigate by clicking Enter in the `PasswordBox` (which will be handled by `HandleTextBox_KeyDown`), the button on the next page is focused. Therefore, I'm curious what causes the button on the next place to be focused, since when you just hit Enter, no control will get focused. What I want is that clicking Enter in the `PasswordBox` behaves exactly like the user would have clicked the `loginButton`.

Comment: I am unsure about why is it happening, but you can cancel the focus. See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but even with this approach I had the issue that only the next control got the focus.

Comment: I have a workaround that make a size 1*1 small button in the top of visual tree.